# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, d3.js

I'm working on a project that requires hierarchical grouping in javascript (for a d3 data viz) and my goal here is for every row that includes the string 'USA', to return the total top count of Method of Murders. In other words, I'm trying to translate the following line of python pandas:

```
df_1[(df_1['Location'].str.contains('USA'))]['Method of 
murder'].value_counts()[:10]
```

into javascript. I'm getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

However I feel even if the error is fixed I won't be returning the results my python pandas code is returning. Any help would be immensely appreciated. Here is my javascript code [Location & MethodOfMurder are column headers in my crimes data].

```
var testTest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.MethodOfMurder; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Location.str.includes("USA"); })

    .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
    .entries(crimes);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(testTest));
```

[image: data]

Comment: Wrap your test block inside an `if(str){}`. That should do

Comment: can you try  and tell console logging value and type of d.Location.str ?

Comment: What is the exact name of your column header? The first snippet refers to `'Method of murder'`while the last one has it as `MethodOfMurder`, which obviously is not the same. Please provide at least a minimal excerpt of your data.

Comment: @altocumulus I added a screenshot of what some of my data looks like. also - my solumn header is MethodOfMurder (it was the former in an earlier stage of the pipeline before being changed this one)